# MySQL vs. JSON - Why?

Tags: mysql, json

I'm designing a little web-app/game. What would be better: MySQL tables or json files? They both store information. They can both be parsed by PHP. What are the advantages/disadvantages?

This is what I mean:

```
username | password
-------------------
seefour  | abc123
```

vs.

```
{
  "username":"seefour",
  "password":"abc123"
}
```

Comment: There are hundred of storage method for data.  Comparing mySQL tables against json files is interesting but not much of a question without a heck of a lot more info about what your needs are.  Otherwise this question will get "opinions and comments" rather than a usable "answer".

Comment: Thanks (please update the question).  user/pass is authentication which is really (another) seperate topic.  Though I would store the pw at least hashed in the db and I don't think I'd be passing it around w/json anyway.

Comment: And on an entirely unrelated note: **don't store passwords!** Whatever system you design, you should *almost certainly* store some kind of hash of your password ([bcrypt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt) is a good choice) instead of the password itself.

Comment: if you are trying to create public datasets, and for example store them on github, then sql will probably more pain than what its worth, json would do fine

Comment: Answers belong in answer posts & not in question posts.

Comment: > some kind of hash of your password < I'm honestly idealistically against storing hashes in a human-readable way in the same place as the username etc (in case of data breaches, some hashes are still crackable), though I'm not aware of a standardized way of storing them in a separate secure place or way that's easily accessible to a typical machine needing the info for authentication.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

To be really blunt about, MySQL is a database while JSON is not, so the correct answer is MySQL, without hesitation. JSON is just a language, and barely even that. JSON was never designed to handle anything like concurrent connections or any sort of data manipulation, since its own function is to *represent* data, not to *manage* it.

So go with MySQL for storing the data. Then you should use some programming language to read that database, and send that information as JSON, rather than actually storing anything in JSON.

If you store the data in files, whether in JSON format or anything else, you will have all sorts of problems that people have stopped worrying about since databases started being used for the same thing. Size limitations, locks, name it. It's good enough when you have one user, but the moment you add more of them, you'll start solving so many problems that you would probably end up by writing an entire database engine just to handle the files for you, while all along you could have simply used an actual database.

Comment: Even with the popularity of JSON today, this still rings true. JSON was never meant to be data storage, and is incredibly inefficient compared to MySQL. Otherwise, MySQL would have used JSON for data storage years ago.

Answer (score 19):

MySQL will be preferable for many reasons, not the least of which being you do not want your web server process to have write access to the filesystem (except for possibly logging) because that is an easy way to get exploited.

Also, the MySQL team has put a lot of engineering effort into things such as replication, concurrent access to data, ACID compliance, and data integrity.

Imagine if, for instance, you add a new field that is required in whatever data structure you are storing.  If you store in JSON files, you will have to have some process that opens each file, adds the field, then saves it.  Compare this to the difficulty of using ALTER TABLE with a DEFAULT value for the field. (A bit of a contrived example, but how many hacks do you want to leave in your codebase for dealing with old data?)

Answer (score 16):

The 2 are not really comparable.

MySQL stores data in a database or actually is a database.
JSON stores data in a format to be passed to and from the server to the client. Javascript/jquery can use JSON as data objects, but they only exist on the client side for the life of the page.

So if you wanted to store data as JSON(not recommended) you'd probably have to store them as text files to save the data.

You should store data in a database.
Use functions to convert it to JSON format, then pass it to the webpage for javascript to consume and present to the user.

Comment: Your answer cleared my confusion. But I have one small question.
Why should we convert SQL data to JSON and then pass it to webpage. Instead we can use SQL Queries to directly fetch the data to webpage. Is converting to JSON and then passing it to webpage more efficient?

Comment: Should never call the database directly from the client side(creating sql scripts to pull data) huge security issues. If the page has not rendered to the client yet(still building on the server) you can call then but frowned upon, should always have some type of service/repository layer that you pass thru.

Comment: If your just pulling the data(thru ajax) and getting just Json(not the full html of the page) then i would think the server would be faster at converting to a json string, then letting a client side  computer try in javascript to convert data to json. Ajax and Json are used as a tool to post/get data without having to post or get the full html of the page. Json is just a formatted string thats easier to hold larger data objects. more object oriented.