# can we use JSON as a database?

Tags: database, json

I'm looking for fast and efficient data storage to build my PHP based web site. I'm aware of MySql. Can I use a JSON file in my server root directory instead of a MySQL database? If yes, what is the best way to do it?

Comment: Mongo DB?  That's kind of like a JSON database ...

Comment: LDAP is would map well to JSON in it's data hierarchy.

Comment: i'm asking can i used a .json file in my root directory to store my data

Comment: without using any database

Comment: Define "fast and efficient data storage" and you define the *systems-based need", not yours to have a "fancy" database layer". Don't make that mistake. Most business needs would gain very little from the D table or NoSQL approach, because their data problem is not structured that way.

Comment: "can i used a .json file.."? No. Don't do that. Unless by database, you mean some config settings.

Comment: You can make a [flat-file database](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flat_file_database) of files. If you're serving a lot of static content, like a wiki or whatnot, that makes sense. But how do you search? Are you going to lay Hibernate or Redis or Doctrine over it? It's the strategy, not the tool.

Comment: You might look at [Drizzle](http://www.drizzle.org/).

Comment: What is the problem if we use json file to store dynamic content

Comment: How do you search? Maintain relationships? Delete records? *Find* records? It's your project. But databases do more than have data sit in them; they're applications that give you access to *information* based on the data *within* them. But do it, it's your project. You might do something really interesting with it.

Comment: in the phpmyadmin we can featch the data as a json file.so why we can't use it in the root directory or any other place

Comment: phpmyadmin is converting the results of a query to JSON, but it's using the mysql database engine to do the work.

Comment: yes.i'm looking at all things. serous example like a payment gateway website .can we archive it using json

Comment: Also, and this is a practical consideration, JSON is plaintext. Don't put it anywhere someone could call up a file and download it, en masse. Like we pointed out, there's already databases that are more or less structured that way. JSON isn't really new either. But it's primarily meant for transport, like XML only way lighter and less descriptive.

Comment: are there any way to restricted it from the public? without using file permission ? so i can test my own db work with only json .it will be fast ?

Comment: Take a look at the [Apache Directory Project](http://directory.apache.org/), which is OpenLDAP with a lot of really great, free tools. LDAP is a database designed to store and manage tree-iike data structures (hence, "directory"), and the most famous is ActiveDirectory. It's great that you've got an idea and are enthusiastic about trying it out, but take a look, at least to get an idea and maybe some ideas.

Comment: Oh, and [Apache Cassandra](http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/DataModel). Take a look at that link. Might this major hybrid DB platform possibly be based on JSON-like data-stores? Hmm... And some more articles: http://www.divconq.com/category/json/ Maybe it's not so crazy after all. `;)`

Comment: You could, but I [wouldn't recommend it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7985145/mysql-vs-json-why)

Comment: I would recommend using [lowdb](https://github.com/typicode/lowdb) if you were to use node.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

You can use any single file, including a JSON file, like this:

- Lock it somehow (google PHP file locking, it's possibly as simple as adding a parameter to file open function or changing function name to locking version).
- Read the data from file and parse it to internal data stucture.
- Optionally modify the data in internal data structure.
- If you modified the data, truncate the file to 0 length and write new data to it.
- Unlock the file as soon as you can, other requests may be waiting...
- You can keep using the data in internal structures to render the page, just remember it may be out-dated as soon as you release the file lock and other HTTP request can modify it.

Also, if you modify the data from user's web form, remember that it may have been modified in between. Like, load page with user details for editing, then other user deletes that user, then editer tries to save the changed details, and should probably get error instead of re-creating deleted user.

**Note**: This is very inefficient. If you are building a site where you expect more than say 10 simultaneous users, you have to use a more sophisticated scheme, or just use existing database... Also, you can't have too much data, because parsing JSON and generating modified JSON takes time.

As long as you have just one user at a time, it'll just get slower and slower as amount of data grows, but as user count increases, and more users means both more requests *and* more data, things start to get *exponentially* slower and you very soon hit limit where HTTP requests start to expire before file is available for handling the request...

At that point, do not try to hack it to make it faster, but instead pick some existing database framework (SQL or nosql or file-based). If you start hacking together your own, you just end up re-inventing the wheel, usually poorly :-). Well, unless it is just programming exercise, but even then it might be better to instead learn use of some existing framework.

Comment: Good write-up. Designing effective and long-running data stores is *hard*. I remember when Brian Aker left MySQL and started Drizzle; his blog was full of all these interesting design challenges and decisions related to it. I left him a couple of comments above about Cassandra, which seems to a full-blown JSON-based distributed data store.

Comment: @hyde : I like this quote: "...reinventing the wheel". I heard that Google Firestore is also based on JSON, are they "reinventing the wheel" that Microsoft SQL Server has been doing great to enforce data integrity, query, and performance all these years?

Comment: +1 for showing the best way possible and explaining the possible pitfalls instead of just discouraging the practice. Great answer.

Comment: "If you modified the data, truncate the file to 0 length and write new data to it." - thats is VERY bad advice, basically it is recipe to loose all the data. It is how Mozilla Thunderbird or Stalker game were destryoing their data on the go. Really, why would you suggest this with a straight face?...

Comment: @Arioch'The Mm yeah. I don't remember what I was thinking back then, >8 years ago. I should probably change it to use atomic file replacememt, or taking a temp backup. However, if losing the data actually matters, using your own file database is not a good way to go anyway.

Answer (score 3):

I wrote an Object Document Mapper to use with json files called [JSON ODM](https://github.com/konsultaner/jsonOdm) may be a bit late, but if it is still needed it is open source under MIT Licence.

It provides a query languge, and some [GeoJSON](http://geojson.org/) tools

Answer (score 2):

The new version of IBM Informix 12.10 xC2 supports now JSON.
check the link : http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/informix/v121/topic/com.ibm.json.doc/ids_json_007.htm

The manual says it is compatible with MongoDB drivers.

> About the Informix JSON compatibility
>
> Applications that use the JSON-oriented query language, created by
>   MongoDB, can interact with data stored in Informix® databases. The
>   Informix database server also provides built-in JSON and BSON (binary
>   JSON) data types.
>
> You can use MongoDB community drivers to insert, update, and query
>   JSON documents in Informix.

Not sure, but I believe you can use the Innovator-C edition (free for production) to test and use it with no-cost either for production enviroment.

Answer (score 1):

One obvious case when you can prefer JSON (or another file format) over database is when all yours (relatively small) data stored in the application cache.

When an application server (re)starts, an application reads data from file(s) and stores it in the data structure.

When data changes, an application updates file(s).

Advantage: no database.

Disadvantage: for a number of reasons can be used only for systems with relatively small data. For example, a very specific product site with several hundreds of products.