# Json vs Mysql data retrieval

Tags: php, mysql, json

I have a JSON file that is 10kb, it never changes and is read-only.

Would it be better to store the data in mysql and retrieve the data that way or json file would be best in that case.

Comment: Context? Scenario? Environment? Usage? Load? Purpose?

Comment: 10,000 daily users all loading the data

Comment: It depends on whether you want to analyse its content in particular ways.

Comment: You'll have to benchmark it on your system and see what's better for you. Just an idea. Since it's 10kB of text, wouldn't it be better to cache it to memory and fetch it from RAM?

Comment: you can use but see this link before use :<br>
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13899342/can-we-use-json-as-a-database