# Grabing information from

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, api

This is my first question on stack overflow so I hope I am doing it correctly.

I'm having trouble finding information regarding information that is pulled from an api and storing that information.

I want to build a small movie app that will pull movies using the OMDB api. This app will display movies that the user will swipe yes or no on (like tinder). I believe the best way for me to do this would be to pull as many movies as I can and store them in a local json file that I will be able to pull from later (because of API usage limit). I want to confirm that this is a bad / good idea and if there are any tools that will make this simpler.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow! :) 

Have you read [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) ? Also, why would you store the movies into a json file and not render them directly to the user? A simple fetch request won't exceed the API limit for sure.

Comment: Good question! I've never heard of a fetch request (still pretty new). Will take a look into them now, thanks!

Comment: I believe you should use MySQL instead of json file, incase of running large amount of data, json file is not a database and wont handle the pressure. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7985145/mysql-vs-json-why

Comment: @YotamDahan that's an overly complicated solution for such a small project. Also why would you store the data in a database if you are already fetching it from a public API ??


I suggest AustinBarton has a read through [this mdn paragraph](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch). Have in mind that fetching data is fundamental part of web development. Good luck in your endevours.

Comment: @ZombieChowder I never used OMDB api, but unless it contains somehow way to check if the movie has been displayed to the user before, it just gonna create an endless loop of movies. I would like to avoid that if I was building such an app.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is something called 'pagination', you don't fetch all the movies at once. OMDB API provides a search endpoint where default value is empty and you can provide a pageNumber parameter

Set up a limit on how much you want to show for your page, and hit the api with pageNumber parameter like `http://www.omdbapi.com/?s=Batman&page=2`.This way you only fetch what you need at that time, and if you scroll more or go to second page, you make another call for getting more records.

For something like this when you just want to swipe left/right - this should work, as making the call first and storing them into DB and then fetching it to show on screen seems a wrong fit. You do not need persistent data here so hitting the API and using that data should work just fine for you.